# User options and validation

Tags: python, validation, user-input, python-3.8

I am trying to get the user to input either 1, 2, or 3. If none of the numbers are entered an error message will be displayed and the program will ask for input again.

How do i identify if what the user typed is either 1,2, or 3?

This is what i currently have.

```
while True:
    try:
        userInput = input("Enter a number: ")
        if userInput not in range(1,4):
    except:
        print('Sorry, invalid entry. Please enter a choice from 1 to 3.')
    elif userInput.isdigit('1'):
        print('1')
    elif userInput.isdigit('2'):
        print('2')
    else:
        print('Thank you for using the Small Business Delivery Program! Goodbye.')
```

Comment: You need to convert your input to `int`:   `userInput = int(input("Enter a number: "))`

Comment: i got the following error : builtins.IndentationError: expected an indented block. on the line that has except

Comment: Your code is not indent properly :) You can learn some basic from this link
https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_indentation.asp

Comment: Please don't edit your question in ways that remove important information. I have rolled back the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check values of the same type.  Your code compares string and int.  You also need to work on the syntax of basic statements: `if <condition>: except:` isn't legal.  Keep it simple:

```
userInput = None

while userInput not in ['1', '2', '3']:
    userInput = input("Enter a number: ")
```

Comment: Thanks; I should have remembered that.  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your input to be in `range(1, 4)`, it needs to be an `int`, not a `str` (which is what's returned by `input()`:

```
while True:
    try:
        userInput = int(input("Enter a number: "))
        assert userInput in range(1, 4)
    except:
        print('Sorry, invalid entry. Please enter a choice from 1 to 3.')
    if userInput == 1:
        print('1')
    if userInput == 2:
        print('2')
    if userInput == 3:
        print('Thank you for using the Small Business Delivery Program! Goodbye.')
        break
```